# redirecting vim :make output to file

Tags: vim

Rather than having vim print the output of the :make command, I want to read the output in a file (which gets updated automatically in vim); so that my compiled file can run right away without having to see the output of the :make command.

I'm using the following makefile

```
all: compile run

compile: file.cc
       g++ -o file file.cc

run: file
       ./file
```

How does one redirect the output of the :make command in a way that it isn't also printed to the screen by vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all we have https://vi.stackexchange.com/ , you can get better answers about Vim in there.

---

Second, I'll argue that a Makefile is no place to run a program, the idea behind `make` is to catch compilation errors.  But assuming you have your reasons (e.g. `./file` opens a graphical display) there are a couple of ways to perform this in Vim:

For a start you can set `makeprg` to perform the redirection:

```
:set makeprg=make\ >/dev/null\ 2>&1
```

(You can change `/dev/null` to an actual file)

But that still leaves the line:

```
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

And asks for confirmation, which may be annoying when you know that there is no output.

---

To get rid of the confirmation line you can use `silent` as follows:

```
set makeprg=make\ >/dev/null\ 2>&1
function! MyMake()
  silent make
  redraw!
endfunction
command Mm call MyMake()
```

And now you can do:

```
:Mm
```

To perform the make and go back to straight to Vim.  (the `redraw!` is needed only in some terminals)

Comment: It does it! How do I make the proces run on background; so the screen doesn't switch to the shell for a split second?

Comment: @MusséRedi - You have two options.  The hacky one is to `set makeprg=make\ >/dev/null\ 2>&1\ &` and leave the entire make process running in the background.  And the proper one is to use channels (see `:h channels`), yet I would advise against channels since they're still very buggy.  (and my experience trying to code something in VimScript with channels was pretty bad.)

Answer (score 1):

You can execute this command:

```
:silent exec "!make >Output" | :redraw!
```

The file `Output` contains the last output of the executed `make` command.

Answer (score 0):

Use `:silent` to remove the output and "press enter" prompt. I suggest a nice mapping or command:

```
command! -nargs=* Smake silent make <args>
nnoremap <f5> :silent make<cr>
```

`:make` will populate the quickfix list with the results from `:make`. Use `:copen` to open the quickfix window.

For more help see:

```
:h :command
:h silent
:h :make
:h 'makeprg'
:h quickfix
```